# ngrx stagger load data with multiple HTTP request

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, angular-http

I am working with an API in an Angular NGRX app that requires I make multiple calls to get all the data I'm looking for.  For example, I start off by requesting a list of groups

```
GET http://api-path/my/groups
```

That returns an array of `id` objects, like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "MDJiZDlmZDYtOGY5My00NzU4LTg3YzMtMWZiNzM3NDBhMzE1IyNkMmM2ZjExMS1mZmFkLTQyYTAtYjY1ZS1lZTAwNDI1NTk4YWE="
    },
    {
        "id": "MDJiZDlmZDYtOGY5My00NzU4LTg3YzMtMWZiNzM3NDBhMzE1IyMxNGQ2OTYyZC02ZWViLTRmNDgtODg5MC1kZTU1NDU0YmIxMzY="
    },
    {
        "id": "MDJiZDlmZDYtOGY5My00NzU4LTg3YzMtMWZiNzM3NDBhMzE1IyMyMGMzNDQwZC1jNjdlLTQ0MjAtOWY4MC0wZTUwYzM5NjkzZGY="
    },
    {
        "id": "MDJiZDlmZDYtOGY5My00NzU4LTg3YzMtMWZiNzM3NDBhMzE1IyMyYTg0OTE5Zi01OWQ4LTQ0NDEtYTk3NS0yYThjMjY0M2I3NDE="
    },
    {
        "id": "MDJiZDlmZDYtOGY5My00NzU4LTg3YzMtMWZiNzM3NDBhMzE1IyMzNGIwMTg1MS1jMTNkLTQ2MDQtYmIzYi01ZGUxZWNiZjAyODg="
    },
    {
        "id": "MDJiZDlmZDYtOGY5My00NzU4LTg3YzMtMWZiNzM3NDBhMzE1IyM1YWY2YTc2Yi00MGZjLTRiYTEtYWYyOS04ZjQ5YjA4ZTQ0ZmQ="
    },
    {
        "id": "MDJiZDlmZDYtOGY5My00NzU4LTg3YzMtMWZiNzM3NDBhMzE1IyM4NmZjZDQ5Yi02MWEyLTQ3MDEtYjc3MS01NDcyOGNkMjkxZmI="
    },
]
```

I then have to make a call for each `id` object to get the details:

```
GET http://api-path/group/{ID}
```

I'm currently using an effect to trigger these calls:

```
  loadGroupSuccess = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(fromActions.loadGroupSuccess),
      delay(this.debounceTime(), asyncScheduler),
      filter(({ group }) => !!team),
      mergeMap(({ group }) => [
        ...group.map((id) =>
          fromActions.loadGroupDetails({ id })
        ),
      ])
    )
  );
```

The `loadGroupDetails` action is received by another effect and makes the call out to the API. I'm currently injecting a random delay between 0-500ms with the `this.debounceTime()` function. If I don't put that in, all of the XHR requests happen at the same time and the browser becomes locked while the data is downloaded.

I feel like there is a better way to handle something like this.  Is there a way to stagger the requests so that only a few happen at a time?  Is there a better way to call out to these APIs than using effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a concurrency param you can set in `mergeMap` which can improve your performance,

```
mergeMap(getHttp, 3)
```

In this case, maximum 3 calls concurrently made at any given time

Comment: That was it! I knew it was going to be something small that I was overlooking.  Thank you for the quick answer!